# How to use @ symbol for Angular context instead of asp.net MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I am using asp.net MVC 4 .cshtml view page to develop some AngularJS codes. On that .cshtml page, I am using $resource object. However, when I define a Angular factory using $resource and its **default parameters** with @ symbol, then the asp.net MVC engine  in VS editor keeps saying compiling error "@userId does not exist in this context.".  Obviously, there is an ambiguity of the @ symbol that is used for Razor context and Angular context.

How can I specify the @ symbol used for Angular only and get rid of that Razor engine error compile message?  Thank you.

I can use an .**HTML** extension file for my view page, but I want use .net MVC .**cshtml** extension file so I do not lose the advantages of the Razor engine and Visual Studio IDE tool (*such as Intellisense, C# server side codes inside .cshtml page, etc*).

Here my codes in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myApp = angular.module("ListPeopleModule", ["ngResource"]);

    myApp.factory("PeopleFactory", function ($resource) {
        return $resource('../Api/GetPeopleApi/GetPeopleByPage/:userId/:sortColumnName', { 

userId: "@userId", sortColumnName: "@sortColumnName"  } , { update: { method: 'PUT'} });
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: @Ajay beniwal, thank you for your simple trick and it works like a charmp.